# How do I copy a database in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2000, database-backups

How do I create a new database that is an exact copy of an existing one in SQL Server 2000?

For example, I have an existing database `DB1`. I wish to create a new database named `DB2` that is the exact copy of the old database `DB1`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how to copy a database in sql 2000?

Answer (score 1):

- Backup the database DB1.
- Create a new database DB2
- Restore the backup of database DB1 in the new database DB2

Comment: I don't think you need to create a new database, you can just restore the old one as the new one -though you'll want to tweak a few things when you do (true either way).

Comment: It is indeed not necessary to create the other DB first.  However, I tend to always do it like that ... It somehow feels safer to me, but I think it is merely psychological. :)